# how to use '~=' to return images that partially match an entered image name / text 

Tags: jquery

Is possible to use this? (the code *format* is mixed html jQuery, but just for explanation.)

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="" /> // the entered text: 'car'
var text= $('#input').text();  // is taken by jquery...
```

And than something like: (to retrieve all combinations of images)

```
<div id="results"></div> // the area inside body...
$('#results').append('<img src~="'+ text +'"'); // the ~ ! (I'm missing some kind of loop here...)
```

And finally append to #result all the matched images like:
carmageddon.png car.jpg red-car.jpg blue-car-micromachines.jpg car-yellow.gif

Having in mind that if entered only 'yellow' to return only the images that have 'yellow'.

**EDIT**:
Resume:
if you type into an input field a name, you can dynamically make appear an image on page, but only if the entered name is equal to the image name on the server. So my question was: you write only a part of the name, and jquery appends to the page all images that partially match the entered name. ... any idea?

any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"I think it's kinda impossible...But, is there a workaround?"* Sure, I work around the impossible six times before breakfast. ;-) (I'm here all week, folks, and don't forget to tip your waitresses.)

Comment: (But seriously) What is the master list that you'd be looking through? Your title is "to find image with similar name that is **not** already on the page", so what's the list to search?

Comment: T.J. I appretiate your answers. I am aware of: if you type into a input field a name, you can dynamically make appear an image, but only if the entered name is equal to the image name on the server. So my question was: you write only a part of the name, and jquery appends to the page all images that partially match the entered name. ... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you've clarified in the edit, you'll have to have server-side code that accepts the search string and returns a list of matching images. Otherwise, there's no way for the client-side code to know what images are available to be shown.

For example, suppose your HTML is this:

```
<input id="imageSearch" type="text" value="" />
```

(I've changed the `id`; **strongly** recommend not using "input" as an `id``.)

Your JavaScript using jQuery might look like this:

```
(function() {                // Scoping function to avoid globals
    var currentSearch;

    $("#imageSearch").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val(); // `val()`, not `text()`
        if (val.length > 2) {    // Or whatever
            // Start a search
            currentSearch = val;
            $.ajax({
                url: "searchpage",
                data: {search: val},
                success: function(data) {
                    var results;

                    // Is this still the current search?
                    // (Remember that network operations may
                    // be chaotic, if the user types another
                    // char you might get the response to your
                    // next call before your response to an
                    // earlier one. Unlikely, but it does happen.)
                    if (val === currentSearch) {
                        // Still current, show results if any
                        results = $("#results");
                        $.each(data.images, function(index, imgurl) {
                            // Already showing this image?
                            if (!results.find("img[src='" + imgurl + "']")[0]) {
                                // No, show it
                                results.append($("<img/>", {src: imgurl}));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })();
```

(For production code, I'd break that up into [named functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) and be a bit more paranoid, but this is just a quick example.)

Your server-side `searchpage` (which you'll have to write with whatever server-side technology you have, e.g., PHP, Java, ASP.Net, etc., etc.) would reply with [JSON](http://json.org) (being sure to set the `Content-Type: application/json` header) which might look like this:

```
{
    "search": "car",
    "images": [
       "carmageddon.png",
       "car.jpg",
       "red-car.jpg",
       "blue-car-micromachines.jpg",
       "car-yellow.gif"
    ]
}
```

E.g., an array of matching relative image URLs. (I included the search term in the reply, which I find handy sometimes; not actually used in the code above.)

Comment: Ah... the allmighty AJAX! :) Thanks T.J.! Just a question... you have `"search":"car"` ... what if the search termin is 'yellow' ? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Matthias: That's just an example of what your server-side code might return in response to a query where "car" was the search term. I find it useful to echo back search terms in search results, to make client-side handling easier. You can leave it out, the code given doesn't actually use it (it uses `currentSearch` and closures instead).

Comment: Thanks a lot... I think I'll make it work! Thanks for the reminder on ID/input (it was a fast-mistake writing my question), but good to be reminded!

Comment: I was just wandering there's some magic-guru inside each's client browser with a magic stick.... I'm right away to make it work! thanks very many!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression for that.

I am assuming that the images are stored in an Array `imgs`.

```
var appendText;
var myReg = '/('+ $('#input').text() +')+/g';
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    foreach( i in imgs ){
        if( myReg.match( imgs[i] ) ){
            appendText += '<img src="'+ imgs[i] +'">';
        }
    }
});
```

and later on you can append the text;

```
$('#results').append( appendText );
```

But here you have to watch out for the pitfalls like what if the input contains the escape characters. you have to replace these characters on the fly.

Comment: You've assumed some magic here: Your `imgs` array. As it turns out, he doesn't have one, it needs to get generated server-side.